# Flutter TextEditingController does not clear the text in a readOnly TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I am trying to make a cancel button for a form. I can clear all the TextFormField successfully except this read-only TextFormField whose value is set by the TextEditingController.

This is the TextFormField. I can set the value of the TextFormField() to the date picked by the user successfully.

```
final _start_time_controller = TextEditingController();
final _finish_time_controller = TextEditingController();

Flexible(
    child: TextFormField(
        onTap: () async {
            final selectedDate = await _selectDateTime(context);
            if(selectedDate == null) return;
            final selectedTime = await _selectTime(context);
            if(selectedTime == null) return;
            setState(() {
                _start_time = DateTime(selectedDate.year,selectedDate.month,selectedDate.day,selectedTime.hour,selectedTime.minute);
                _start_time_controller.text = _start_time.toString();
            });
        },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Start Time',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
    ),
    controller: _start_time_controller,
    readOnly: true,
    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Start Time can\'t be empty' : null,
    ),                         
),
```

This is the cancel button.

```
Expanded(
    child: RoundedButton(
        text: 'Cancel',
        buttonColor: Colors.grey,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        press: cancel,
    ),
) ,
```

This is the cancel function.

```
void cancel(){
    _start_time = null;
    _finish_time = null;
    _start_time_controller.clear();
    _finish_time_controller.clear();
    formKey.currentState.reset();
}
```

I have tried to wrap the two TextEditingController.clear() call in a setstate() function, however it does not work.

Comment: how about `_start_time_controller.text = ""`?

Comment: adding to 'John Joe' suggest, wrap with setState like below `setState(() => _start_time_controller.text = "")`

Comment: You can add listeners to the controller and set/reset the values like in this [example](https://pastebin.com/DvWqH6mX)

Answer (score 1):

If `TextEditingController.clear()` doesn't clear the value on the TextFormField, it's likely that the value is being set when the screen is rebuilt. A workaround for this issue is to just set a new text value on the TextEditingController.

```dart
setState(() {
  _start_time_controller.text = '';
  _finish_time_controller.text = '';
});
```